# Flowplayer Flash overlay feature and ios compatibility

Tags: ios, flash, video, flowplayer, overlays

I have a Flowplayer flash issue. I'm using multiple video overlays and the player works perfectly on multiple desktop browsers but not on ios devices. I've tried the iPad js include and .ipad(). but nothing works. Can anyone point out the flaw here or a work around to get this to play on ios devices? Here's the full code... Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.angelmedflight.com/flowplayer/example/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.angelmedflight.com/flowplayer/flowplayer.ipad-3.2.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
#overlay {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 720px;
    height: 466px;
    background-image: url('http://www.angelmedflight.com/assets/images/BlackBox.png');
}
.close {
    background: url('http://www.angelmedflight.com/assets/images/close.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover {
    background: url('http://www.angelmedflight.com/assets/images/closeHover.png') no-repeat;
}
#player {
    display: block;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #111;
    border-right: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#player *:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}
</style>

<script>

$(function () {
    var player = $f("player", "http://angelmedflight.com/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf").ipad();

    $("a[rel]").overlay({
      mask: {
        color: '#000',
        opacity: 0.8
      },
      onLoad: function () {
        player.play(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
      },
      onClose: function () {
        player.unload();
      }
    });

  });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="ls-layer">
    <img class="ls-bg" src="assets/images/carousel/video1.jpg" />

    <a rel="#overlay" href="http://www.angelmedflight.com/video/Process_640x360_vegas_i.mp4"><img class="ls-s1" src="http://www.angelmedflight.com/assets/images/carousel/layer_play_button.png" /></a>

</div>

<div id="overlay">
    <a class="close"></a>           

    <div id="player">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't work" what exactly is the experience?

Does it not load the video at all or just not load it in an overlay?

I believe the plugin opens the player in fullscreen mode and customizes the appearance of this mode.

When a player is loaded in full screen mode on iOS it is rendered in the system player, so the JS you are trying to use would have no effect.

If it is not playing at all, I cannot help you. Perhaps you could provide more information.